# custom word removal from a list in python

Tags: python, list, function, stop-words

I am writing a function to do custom word removal, stemming (getting the root form of the word) and then tf-idf.

My input data to the function is a list. If I try to do custom word removal on individual list, that works, but when I combine it in the function, I get an attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Here is my code:

```
def tfidf_kw(K):    
    # Select docs in cluster K
    docs = np.array(mydata2)[km_r3.labels_==K]

    ps= PorterStemmer()
    stem_docs = []
    for doc in docs:
        keep_tokens = []
        
        for token in doc.split(' '):
            #custom stopword removal
            my_list = ['model', 'models', 'modeling', 'modelling', 'python', 
           'train','training', 'trains', 'trained','test','testing', 'tests','tested']
            
            token  = [sub_token for sub_token in list(doc) if sub_token not in my_list]

            stem_token=ps.stem(token)
            keep_tokens.append(stem_token)

        keep_tokens =' '.join(keep_tokens)
        stem_docs.append(keep_tokens)

        return(keep_tokens)
```

Further code is for tf-idf, which works. This is where I need help, to understand what am I doing wrong?

```
token  = [sub_token for sub_token in list(doc) if sub_token not in my_list]
```

Here is the complete error:

```
AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-528a540678b0> in <module>
     49     #return(sorted_df)
     50 
---> 51 tfidf_kw(0)

<ipython-input-154-528a540678b0> in tfidf_kw(K)
     20 
     21 
---> 22             stem_token=ps.stem(token)
     23             keep_tokens.append(stem_token)
     24 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py in stem(self, word)
    650 
    651     def stem(self, word):
--> 652         stem = word.lower()
    653 
    654         if self.mode == self.NLTK_EXTENSIONS and word in self.pool:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

On line 51, where it says `tfidf_kw(0)`, that's where I am checking the function for k=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `ps.stem` method expects a single word (a string) as argument, but you are passing a list of strings.

Since you are already inside a `for token in doc.split(' ')` loop it does not seem to make sense to me to use a list comprehension `[... for sub_token in list(doc) ...]` additionally.

If your goal is to skip those tokens that are in `my_list`, presumably you want to write the `for token in doc.split(' ')` loop like this:

```
for token in doc.split(' '):
    my_list = ['model', 'models', 'modeling', 'modelling', 'python', 
   'train','training', 'trains', 'trained','test','testing', 'tests','tested']

    if token in my_list:
        continue
    
    stem_token=ps.stem(token)
    keep_tokens.append(stem_token)
```

Here, if `token` is one of the words in `my_list`, the `continue` statement skips the rest of the current iteration and the loop continues with the next `token`.

Comment: Awesome that works, however, for k=0, I expect 124 rows, but when i check the keep_tokens variable, I only the see 1 row. i.e the above tokenization gets applied to only 1 row.

Comment: I noticed that you have the `return` line inside the loop - you should probably move that out of the loop, that might explain this behaviour. You should probably also return `stem_docs` and not `keep_tokens`.